Why does the square-rectangle problem break Liskov substitution?
The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) imposes four behavioral requirements on subtypes (directly from Wikipedia):

Preconditions cannot be strengthened in the subtype
Postconditions cannot be weakened in the subtype
Invariants cannot be weakened in the subtype
History constraint (the "history rule"). Objects are regarded as being modifiable only through their methods [...]

There is the somewhat famous square-rectangle (or circle-ellipse) problem that breaks the LSP, but I'd like to understand which of the conditions it is actually breaking.
The problem is as follows: we have a Square which is-a Rectangle. We can set the width, w, and height, h, of Rectangle, which in the case of a Square are overridden to modify both width and height at the same time (i.e., Square.setWidth is implemented to set both w and h to the same value).
Now, we introduce another class method squeeze which changes h to h/2. If this is called on Square, the invariant of w==h is violated.
Intuitively, then, we'd be breaking the invariant condition from above, but it seems that the problem is that we have strengthened an invariant in the subtype (the original invariant being only that w,h >= 0).
We also haven't weakened a postcondition. Again, if anything we must have strengthened the postcondition that w==h after any operation on Square that is not there for Rectangle.
I don't see how preconditions are relevant.
For the history constraint, we have only used class methods.

The Liskov substitution principal is problematic if you treat a square/circle as if it was a rectangle/ellipse in that the two things act differently.
For example, if you change the height of a 5x5 rectangle to 6, it becomes a 5x6 rectangle. If you do the same thing to a square, it becomes a 6x6 square. So, if you have a test case that checks width is unchanged after changing height, it will act differently between the two shapes:
def test_case_1():
    r = rectangle(5, 5)
    r.set_height(6)
    assert r.get_width() == 5  # OKAY

def test_case_2():
    r = square(5)
    r.set_height(6)
    assert r.get_width() == 5  # FAILS

This would be a pre-condition strengthening violation. Since a rectangle has a pre-condition where the width is independent of the height, the square violates this by tying them together.
Hence, according to LSP, a square is not a special type of rectangle. For my purposes, I wouldn't even define a square. I would instead define a rectangle with three member functions that can set height, width, or both. Then the problem goes away :-)

I think what you're saying makes sense but it's phrased in a way where it seems like you're describing an invariant as opposed to a precondition? Is it maybe better to say that a precondition to squeeze is that the height and width are independent?

(also I agree that having just Rectangle is likely the better design, but the example is just to better understand the LSP)

The Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP):

Subclasses should be substitutable for their base classes.

This means that a user of a base class should continue to function properly if a derivative of that base class is passed to it.
The user assumes that if you provide him with methods for setting the width and height, he will be able to change them independently. But if the user works with a Square instead of a Rectangle, setting the height will implicitly change the width, and trying to get the width, the user will get a value that is not what he would expect. This is a violation of the principle.

Bertrand Meyer in Design by Contract says:

…when redefining a routine [in a derivative], you may only replace its
precondition by a weaker one, and its postcondition by a stronger one.

This means you can only reduce the set of preconditions and only extend the set of postconditions.
You can think of the set of postconditions as a set of tests, where all tests for the base type must pass for an object of the subtype.
// postcondition
void test(Rectangle rectangle) {
    rectangle.setWidth(1);
    rectangle.setHight(1);

    rectangle.setWidth(3);

    // is violated for a square
    assert rectangle.getHight() == 1;
}


Thanks for your answer. What you're saying is correct but I'm looking for something more precise.

@user2978125 What do you mean by the word precise in the context of the principle? Unfortunately, all solid principles do not have a formal verification algorithm.

Liskov and Wing (1994) lays out precise mathematical definitions for what it means for a type to be a subtype of another type (this is the LSP formally). Ideally, I would like to understand the LSP in this context, but also using the slightly less formal conditions I have listed in my question. I agree most SOLID principles are not at this level but this does not include the LSP.

@user2978125 I tried to supplement the answer taking into account your comments.
